# Создание Pivot таблицы с одинаковыми значениями Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Я делаю чат и у меня появилась задача сделать ответ на сообщения
У меня есть морф таблица с сообщениями.
Хочу сделать pivot таблица сообщений с сообщениями.

```
id - integer
message_id - integer
message_id - integer
```

Делаю миграцию и получаю ошибку

```
1060 Duplicate column name 'message_id'
```

Что делать и как быть с такой таблицей?

Comment: mysql не нравится, что поле которые вы хотите создать уже есть в таблице

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, зачем промежуточная таблица, если все сообщения хранятся в одной таблице. Или не в одной?

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh, да я понимаю что они есть , но вот как сделать правильно ни как не придумаю

Comment: @РустамГимранов чтобы связывать одно сообщение с другими , так как ответ может состоять из 2-3 сообщений. Например как у ВК, выделяем сообщения и отвечаем них

Comment: сделайте отдельную таблицу hasMany, чтобы хранить в ней ответ и id сообщения